# How can I use a variable from another class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, variables

Please help me how can I use a variable from **deviation_2DArray.java**
into **NBC.java**, in **NBC.java** I want to average `b[i]` by `d[i][j]` and `c[j]`

Example:

```
b[1]=avg (d[1][1]+d[1][2]+.....+d[1][5])
```

Thanks in advance.

**2DArray.java**

```
public class 2DArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[][] d = new double[6][4];

        double[][] e = {
            {}, {
                0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0
            }, {
                0.0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1
            }, {
                0.0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4
            }, {
                0.0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.7
            }, {
                0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9
            }
        };

        double[] avg = new double[4];
        double[] sum = new double[4];
        int i, j, k;

        //average of column
        for (j = 1; j < e[1].length; j++) {
            for (i = 1; i < e.length; i++)
            System.out.println("e[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + e[i][j]);
        }

        for (j = 1; j < e[1].length; j++) {

            sum[j] = 0.0;
            k = 0;
            for (i = 1; i < e.length; i++)

            if (e[i][j] > 0.0) {
                sum[j] += e[i][j];
                k++;
            }
            avg[j] = sum[j] / k;

            System.out.println("Average of j[" + j + "] = " + avg[j]);

        }

        for (j = 1; j < e[1].length; j++) {
            for (i = 1; i < e.length; i++)

            if (e[i][j] > 0.0) {

                d[i][j] = Math.abs(e[i][j] - avg[j]);
                System.out.println("d[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + d[i][j]);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

**NBC.java**

```
public class NBC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] b = new double[6];
        double[] c = new double[4];
        int count;

        b[i] = d[i][j] / count;
    }

}
```

Comment: ummm both of these classes are just using the main method. which is static and doesnt make a difference what class its in... move all the code out of NBC into the other class and just use 1 main method.... Otherwise you need to declare the variables outside the main method and create getters and setters.

Answer (score 1):

I'll resume it to one simple word: [getters](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/getter.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create class-level fields in the `2DArray` class and provide getter methods to those fields. Then `NBC` would need to have an instance of `2DArray` unless you made those fields / getters static.

Currently your `d` variable in `2DArray` is only in the scope of the main method, therefore just providing a getter won't solve the problem because `d` only has scope in the method.

Also, each class has its own `main` method. You can only execute one `main` per application. So how is your flow of control getting from `2DArray` to `NBC`? If `2DArray` is calling `NBC`, then you could pass the array as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in the 2DArray something like this:

```
public double getElement(int i, int j) {
  return d[i][j];
}
```

Comment: `d` is not a field. It is defined in the `main` method.